# Most suitable file formats for exporting a text chat from a chat application

Tags: accessibility, copy-paste, chat

This post may be more appropriate on Super User Stack Exchange.

Please migrate my post there if more appropriate.

I was wondering what the best file format world be for exporting a chat from a messaging application:

1. For machine processing.
2. For incorporating into a word document.

I ask, because I would like to make some suggestions to some Android app developers regarding including some support in their apps for chat export, with the most suitable file formats.

Thank you for your support.

Thanks.

Comment: Tell the developers what you need and why. How to do it if thier job

Comment: For machine processing common formats are JSON or XML. For humans an HTML export would be best. But common developers should know all that.